# Chrome extension storage.sync.set in content script throws exception

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a weird issue that wasted too much time.
I have content script that tries to read some data from the storage.sync API but it fails.

I've added the storage permission
and I was able to work with the storage.sync API in the options.js file.

Can you spot what went wrong?

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {   

     chrome.storage.sync.get([
            'var1',
            'var2',        
        ], function(items) {        
            alert("got it");
     });
}
```

This is the error message:

> CONTENT_SCRIPT context for xxxxx) Lazy require of extension.binding did not set the binding field
>
> (CONTENT_SCRIPT context for xxxxx) extensions::lastError:82: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object{TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
>       at Object.clear (extensions::lastError:82:23)
>       at handleResponse (extensions::sendRequest:84:15)
>       at restore
>       at HTMLDocument.}

Comment: It's not really clear from what you've provided whether your snippet and the error are related.

Comment: It's related I used the debugger and this error showed right after the call to the storage API. this is a simplified version of the code.

Comment: Well, you're going to have to come up with a [MCVE] that demonstrates the problem because as it is, there isn't any clear way anyone can help you other than simply guessing.

Comment: This is the minimal and complete example, what the error message says?
I couldn't track it down, it points to the storage API call.

Comment: This is obviously not a [MCVE]. There's no easy way for anyone to reproduce this and your error message is obviously from a larger codebase.

Comment: once you follow pvg adcice the error line numbers will match the code line numbering and we can start helping.

Comment: the line numbers point to the chrome.store.sync.get function

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. Including a *manifest.json*, some of the background/content/popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: The reason that a [mcve] is required is that *we want to help*. It is **much** easier to help if we don't have to recreate any of the code needed to duplicate the problem. This is code that you already have. So, please help us to help you and provide a *complete* [mcve] that duplicates the problem with such questions. Without a [mcve] the amount of effort required to even begin to help you is **much** higher which *significantly* reduces the number of people willing/able to help you. Even if we put out the extra effort, we have to *guess* at significant portions of what your problem might be.

Comment: This is an error relating to a chrome extension. Use the ID given to find the extension and disable it.

Comment: @Makyen, pvg: This error is quite 'exceptional' indeed. I too am getting this error, and it does seem being caused by unrelated changes. Only common part between OP's code and mine is adding an event listener (for a custom event in my case). The error (with #line linked) is absolutely useless.

Comment: @0xc0de, In order to investigate the issue, we need enough code to duplicate the error. As written, not enough information is provided for us to do so without making significant assumptions about the code. Even with such assumptions, it may not be possible to duplicate the error with just the code provided. It is the responsibility of the OP to provide a [mcve] which duplicates the problem. While a [MCVE] is a requirement for debugging questions on SO, it's the reasons behind that requirement which are important (e.g. determining that an answer actually solves the problem, etc., etc.).

Answer (score 30):

I had the same error and it was caused due to debugger stopping the flow of execution in the middle.
Once I removed the debugger / breakpoints in my 'Content Script' and 'Background Script' and reloaded everything then I didn't see the error.

Comment: This helped some times, the solution by @deprog (disable-reenable)  other times.

Answer (score 14):

I was also getting this same error. I fixed it by disabling and re-enabling my Chrome browser extensions. Hope that helps.

Comment: This helped some times, the solution by @Sudheer (unset debugging breakpoints) other times.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when injecting code into a html page. Using new id's immediately after injecting them into the page html seems to crash the debugger but not the page itself. Everything works and the error message only pops once on injecting the code. **It looks like it was coming from the cache.** It just happened once on refreshing the page and never after clearing cache... Sorry not very useful, but this is what I had and could not reproduce anymore.